# IOS Chart compiler warnings with Xcode 11.5

Tags: swift, xcode11, ios-charts

I've just upgraded to 11.5.  Compiler is now throwing out warnings (var -> let) for IOS Charts.  Is it possible to remove these only for the Charts module i.e. I don't want to remove warnings for the rest of my own code (I'm reluctant to go into the Charts module and change the source, even though the changes are trivial).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go the Target's `Build Settings` and set `Inhibit All Warnings` to `YES`.

**OR**

If you're using cocoapods you can automatically set it to `YES` by adding these lines into your `Podfile`

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS'] = "YES"
    end
  end
end
```

**OR**

Just declare `inhibit_all_warnings!` in top of your `Podfile`.

If you want to disable / enable warnings for specific pods use `:inhibit_warnings => true` or `:inhibit_warnings => false` in the pod line. Then you should execute `pod install`

```rb
platform :ios

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

# ignore warnings from a specific pod
pod 'Charts', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

---

[Cocoapods Inhibit All Warnings Documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#inhibit_all_warnings_bang)

Comment: Thanks, that works, I used your feedback to edit the podfile which I found under the Pods project in the Xcode Project Navigator.  I appreciate your help.